# How do I define the security rules where only logged in user can read and write all of the collections and subcollection?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I have these collections of `category`, `products`, and `orders`. And then under the `products` I have a subcollection of `history`. Also in my app, there is only 1 type of user which I add here directly in the Firebase console. How can I define the security rules where only logged in user can read and write on these collections and subcollections?

[image]

For the logging in, I am using Firebase Authentication:

```
const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const auth = getAuth();
    console.log(email, password, "1");
    setIsLoading(true);
    signInWithEmailAndPassword(auth, email, password)
      .then((userCredential) => {
        // Signed in

        const user = userCredential.user;
        setIsLoading(false);
        navigate("/Homepage");
        // ...
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        const errorCode = error.code;
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        setIsLoading(false);
        alert(errorMessage);
      });
  };
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I define the security rules where only logged in user can read and write on these collections and subcollections?

The following rule is using a wildcard and should allow any user that is authenticated to read and write to *any* document in Firestore:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

If you want to lock it down at some point, because you introduce a collection that not all users should have access to, you can make it explicit:

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /category/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /products/{id} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }

    match /logs/{id} {
      allow read, write: if false;
    }
  }
}
```

For further information, [start here in the docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/get-started) and use the Playground in Firebase Console to test your rules before deploying them.

Comment: I can just use the first example, right? Since I'm adding the users via the firebase console directly and then all of those logged in users can create, read and write

Comment: How you add users to Firebase Auth doesn't matter. As long as the user on the client is authenticated with Firebase Auth by the time they make the request to Firestore, they should pass the Security Rule (because `auth` doesn't equal `null` anymore).